# How can i notify in Micrososft Teams when a Record created in Salesforce?

Tags: integration, notification

I am trying to generate Microsoft Teams notification for case Owner when a new case is created in salesforce. How can I achieve this for individual chats and Teams?.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Microsoft Team's notification API to send messages to that platform from Salesforce.

On Salesforce I suggest you use a record-triggered flow to run an Apex action that calls that service.

The documentation for that API can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-send-activityfeednotifications?tabs=http#send-activity-feed-notifications-to-users.

Answer (score 0):

There's an App I discovered that can make this easy, no API work is required. Maybe it helps you out? https://www.cyfunolabs.com